# How to resolve the node items of array from the property in typescript compiler api and ts-morph?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

I wondering if it's possible to get the nodes items of the array by using some method of typescript compiler api?

In my code I pass `NAMES` array to `names` property and I can do it with different ways like so:

```
const NAMES = ['John', 'Jack'];
const LAST_NAMES = ['Herbert', 'Moore'];

const person = {
   names: NAMES,
   lastNames: LAST_NAMES
};
```

Or by spread operator:

```
const NAMES = ['John', 'Jack'];
const LAST_NAMES = ['Herbert', 'Moore'];

const person = {
   names: [...NAMES],
   lastNames: [...LAST_NAMES]
};
```

Or:

```
const NAMES = ['John', 'Jack'];
const LAST_NAMES = ['Herbert', 'Moore'];

const person = {
   names: [...Object.values(NAMES)],
   lastNames: [...Object.values(LAST_NAMES)]
};
```

Or:

```
const person = {
   names: ['John', 'Jack'],
   lastNames: ['Herbert', 'Moore']
};
```

In the end I don't care how user is writing the code, I just care about the items nodes in the array.

Is there some function/method can help me to resolve them from `names` property? because I don't want to write code that check for each cases.

```
const person = {
   names */<-- I'm here, how do I get the nodes of the array? */ : [...NAMES], 
   lastNames: [...LAST_NAMES]
};
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-einstein-z2q7x8?file=/src/index.ts)

```
import {
  Project,
  SyntaxKind,
  PropertyAssignment,
  ts,
  ClassDeclaration
} from "ts-morph";

console.clear();

const project = new Project({
  skipAddingFilesFromTsConfig: true
});

const appSourceFile = project.createSourceFile(
  "app.ts",
  `
  const NAMES = ['John', 'Jack'];
  const LAST_NAMES = ['Herbert', 'Moore'];
  
  const person = {
     names: [...Object.values(NAMES)],
     lastNames: [...Object.values(LAST_NAMES)]
  };
`
);

const names = appSourceFile
  .getDescendantsOfKind(SyntaxKind.Identifier)
  .find((n) => n.getText() === "names");

const arrayLiteralExpression = (names.getParent() as PropertyAssignment).getInitializer();

console.log({ arrayLiteralExpression }); <--???
```